# In angular there is a problem to select combobox in selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have already tried with select option and

```
WebElement scanEle = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(5))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
    By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/mat-option[1]/span")));
Actions action = new Actions(getDriver());
action.moveToElement(scanEle).click().build().perform();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-11"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field></section><section _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-row flex-wrap"><div _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-field-label"><label _ngcontent-jkt-c148="">Full residential address *</label></div><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field addressField ng-tns-c91-12 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-12"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-12"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-12"><input _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formcontrolname="address" type="text" matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c91-12 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-name="address" ng-reflect-type="text" required="" id="mat-input-5" aria-required="true"><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-12"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c91-12 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c91-12"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-12" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-12 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-12"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field></section><section _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-row flex-wrap"><div _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-field-label"><label _ngcontent-jkt-c148="">Zip *</label></div><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field addSubField ng-tns-c91-13 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-13"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-13"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-13"><input _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formcontrolname="zip" type="number" matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c91-13 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-name="zip" ng-reflect-type="number" required="" id="mat-input-6" aria-required="true"><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-13"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c91-13 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c91-13"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-13" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-13 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-13"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field><div _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-field-label"><label _ngcontent-jkt-c148="">State *</label></div><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field addSubField ng-tns-c91-14 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-native-select mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-star-inserted"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-14"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-14"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-14"><select _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formcontrolname="state" matnativecontrol="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c91-14 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-name="state" ng-reflect-placeholder="Select State" required="" id="mat-input-7" data-placeholder="Select State" aria-required="true"><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="1" ng-reflect-value="1" class="ng-star-inserted">Alabama</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="2" ng-reflect-value="2" class="ng-star-inserted">Alaska</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="3" ng-reflect-value="3" class="ng-star-inserted">Arizona</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="4" ng-reflect-value="4" class="ng-star-inserted">Arkansas</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="5" ng-reflect-value="5" class="ng-star-inserted">California</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="6" ng-reflect-value="6" class="ng-star-inserted">Colorado</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="7" ng-reflect-value="7" class="ng-star-inserted">Connecticut</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="8" ng-reflect-value="8" class="ng-star-inserted">Delaware</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="9" ng-reflect-value="9" class="ng-star-inserted">District of Columbia</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="10" ng-reflect-value="10" class="ng-star-inserted">Florida</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="11" ng-reflect-value="11" class="ng-star-inserted">Georgia</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="12" ng-reflect-value="12" class="ng-star-inserted">Hawaii</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="13" ng-reflect-value="13" class="ng-star-inserted">Idaho</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="14" ng-reflect-value="14" class="ng-star-inserted">Illinois</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="15" ng-reflect-value="15" class="ng-star-inserted">Indiana</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="16" ng-reflect-value="16" class="ng-star-inserted">Iowa</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="17" ng-reflect-value="17" class="ng-star-inserted">Kansas</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="18" ng-reflect-value="18" class="ng-star-inserted">Kentucky</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="19" ng-reflect-value="19" class="ng-star-inserted">Louisiana</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="20" ng-reflect-value="20" class="ng-star-inserted">Maine</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="21" ng-reflect-value="21" class="ng-star-inserted">Montana</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="22" ng-reflect-value="22" class="ng-star-inserted">Nebraska</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="23" ng-reflect-value="23" class="ng-star-inserted">Nevada</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="24" ng-reflect-value="24" class="ng-star-inserted">New Hampshire</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="25" ng-reflect-value="25" class="ng-star-inserted">New Jersey</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="26" ng-reflect-value="26" class="ng-star-inserted">New Mexico</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="27" ng-reflect-value="27" class="ng-star-inserted">New York</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="28" ng-reflect-value="28" class="ng-star-inserted">North Carolina</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="29" ng-reflect-value="29" class="ng-star-inserted">North Dakota</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="30" ng-reflect-value="30" class="ng-star-inserted">Ohio</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="31" ng-reflect-value="31" class="ng-star-inserted">Oklahoma</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="32" ng-reflect-value="32" class="ng-star-inserted">Oregon</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="33" ng-reflect-value="33" class="ng-star-inserted">Maryland</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="34" ng-reflect-value="34" class="ng-star-inserted">Massachusetts</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="35" ng-reflect-value="35" class="ng-star-inserted">Michigan</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="36" ng-reflect-value="36" class="ng-star-inserted">Minnesota</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="37" ng-reflect-value="37" class="ng-star-inserted">Mississippi</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="38" ng-reflect-value="38" class="ng-star-inserted">Missouri</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="39" ng-reflect-value="39" class="ng-star-inserted">Pennsylvania</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="40" ng-reflect-value="40" class="ng-star-inserted">Rhode Island</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="41" ng-reflect-value="41" class="ng-star-inserted">South Carolina</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="42" ng-reflect-value="42" class="ng-star-inserted">South Dakota</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="43" ng-reflect-value="43" class="ng-star-inserted">Tennessee</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="44" ng-reflect-value="44" class="ng-star-inserted">Texas</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="45" ng-reflect-value="45" class="ng-star-inserted">Utah</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="46" ng-reflect-value="46" class="ng-star-inserted">Vermont</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="47" ng-reflect-value="47" class="ng-star-inserted">Virginia</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="48" ng-reflect-value="48" class="ng-star-inserted">Washington</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="49" ng-reflect-value="49" class="ng-star-inserted">West Virginia</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="50" ng-reflect-value="50" class="ng-star-inserted">Wisconsin</option><!--ng-container--><option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" value="51" ng-reflect-value="51" class="ng-star-inserted">Wyoming</option><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--></select><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-14"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c91-14 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-21" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" for="mat-input-7" aria-owns="mat-input-7"><span class="ng-tns-c91-14 ng-star-inserted">Select State</span><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c91-14 ng-star-inserted"> *</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c91-14 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c91-14"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-14" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-14 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-14"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field></section><section _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formgroupname="spouse" class="form-row flex-wrap ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="spouse" style="display: none;"><div _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="form-field-label"><label _ngcontent-jkt-c148="">Spouse Name *</label></div><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field salutationCtrl ng-tns-c91-15 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-select mat-form-field-appearance-outline mat-form-field-can-float ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-appearance="outline"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-15"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-15"><div class="mat-form-field-outline ng-tns-c91-15 ng-star-inserted"><div class="mat-form-field-outline-start ng-tns-c91-15" style="width: 0px;"></div><div class="mat-form-field-outline-gap ng-tns-c91-15" style="width: 0px;"></div><div class="mat-form-field-outline-end ng-tns-c91-15"></div></div><div class="mat-form-field-outline mat-form-field-outline-thick ng-tns-c91-15 ng-star-inserted"><div class="mat-form-field-outline-start ng-tns-c91-15" style="width: 0px;"></div><div class="mat-form-field-outline-gap ng-tns-c91-15" style="width: 0px;"></div><div class="mat-form-field-outline-end ng-tns-c91-15"></div></div><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-15"><mat-select _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" formcontrolname="initials" class="mat-select ng-tns-c147-16 ng-tns-c91-15 mat-select-empty ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-name="initials" aria-labelledby="mat-select-value-7" id="mat-select-6" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false"><div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c147-16"><div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c147-16" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" id="mat-select-value-7"><span class="mat-select-placeholder mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c147-16 ng-star-inserted"></span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c147-16"><div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c147-16"></div></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-offset-y": "0"
}--></mat-select><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-15"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-15" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-15 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-15"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field nameCtrl ng-tns-c91-17 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-float-label="never"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-17"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-17"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-17"><input _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formcontrolname="firstName" type="text" matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c91-17 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-name="firstName" ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="First name" id="mat-input-8" data-placeholder="First name" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false"><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-17"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c91-17 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-25" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" for="mat-input-8" aria-owns="mat-input-8"><span class="ng-tns-c91-17 ng-star-inserted">First name</span><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c91-17 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c91-17"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-17" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-17 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-17"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field><mat-form-field _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" class="mat-form-field form-field nameCtrl ng-tns-c91-18 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-float-label="never"><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c91-18"><div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c91-18"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c91-18"><input _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" formcontrolname="lastName" type="text" matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c91-18 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored" ng-reflect-name="lastName" ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="Last name" id="mat-input-9" data-placeholder="Last name" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false"><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c91-18"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c91-18 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-27" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" for="mat-input-9" aria-owns="mat-input-9"><span class="ng-tns-c91-18 ng-star-inserted">Last name</span><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c91-18 ng-star-inserted"><span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c91-18"></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c91-18" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c91-18 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c91-18"></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--></div></div></mat-form-field></section><button _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" mat-raised-button="" color="primary" type="submit" class="mat-focus-indicator nextCtrl mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary mat-button-disabled" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-disabled="true" disabled="true"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Next</span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="true" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button></form></div></app-req-appt-patient-personal-info><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "personal-info"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "contact-info"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "insurance-info"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "health-history"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "immunisation"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "additional-info"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "user-agreement"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "appt-preview"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "prob-check-list"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "add-family-member"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "spouse-contact-info"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "provider-selection"
}--></section></app-request-appointment><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-portal": ""
}--></mat-dialog-container><div tabindex="0" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor" aria-hidden="true"></div></div></div><div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div><div class="cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box" dir="ltr" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><div id="cdk-overlay-2" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="min-width: 63px; font-size: 14px; bottom: 14.25px; left: 321px; transform: translateX(-16px) translateY(-13px);"><div class="mat-select-panel-wrap ng-tns-c147-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanelWrap ng-star-inserted"><div role="listbox" tabindex="-1" class="ng-tns-c147-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel mat-select-panel mat-primary" style="transform-origin: 50% 20.875px 0px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);" id="mat-select-0-panel" aria-multiselectable="false"><mat-option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-active ng-tns-c147-2 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="44" id="mat-option-4" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="mat-option-text">Mr</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div></mat-option><!--ng-container--><mat-option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c147-2 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="45" id="mat-option-5" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="mat-option-text">Mrs</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div></mat-option><!--ng-container--><mat-option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c147-2 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="46" id="mat-option-6" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="mat-option-text">Ms </span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div></mat-option><!--ng-container--><mat-option _ngcontent-jkt-c148="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c147-2 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-value="47" id="mat-option-7" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style=""><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="mat-option-text">Mx</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div></mat-option><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--></div></div></div></div></div><div class="cdk-live-announcer-element cdk-visually-hidden" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite"></div></body></html>
```

[image: This is coming while we are selecting dropdown from angular site with selenium. When we select salutation then this error comes.]

Comment: Can you please add relevant HTML snippet?

Comment: I tried to upload file of code but not attaching so pasted html

Comment: what is going wrong here? the element isn't clickable?

Comment: option not selecting in combo box

Comment: Is [this link](https://forum.katalon.com/t/error-in-select-by-value-function-angular/63945/5) related?